# ContentVersion Trigger not fired upon upload of private Chatter File

Tags: apex, trigger

We have create an APEX Trigger with following Type:

```
trigger TestContentVersionUpsertTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert, after update) { 

system.debug('Trigger for ContentVersion invoked');
....... 
......
}
```

When we upload a chatter file or share a file by admin user which eventually updated ContentVersion table as a result this trigger will be fired, but when any other non-admin user upload a chatter file, this trigger will NOT be fired.

It is understandable that file uploaded by non-admin user is his private file so admin couldn't access it. But following questions arises:

- Does APEX Trigger(installed by admin) also couldn't have access to private files of non-admin users in the DB?
- Has entry of private file been inserted in ContentVersion table or not?

Note: Above scenario is also happening for ContentDocument table

Thanks a lot for any help.

Zeeshan

Comment: This seems be a bug or Working as Designed -- lengthy discussion here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005K7H